# Set the random seed for a Dataset to always select the same images / pearson correlation

Tags: python, tensorflow, random-seed

I'm an absolute beginner in programming, so please be nice :)
I have developed a neural network for image quality analysis. I installed Pandas, Tensorflow and Numpy beforehand. Then I imported my dataset, output it with the help of pandas and let the "Votes" average for the last column.
In the dataset, each line counts as a separate image, which was rated for quality by test persons.

I divided my dataset into training and test data (80% / 20%). And then created a model with 3 levels. This model is then trained with 1000 epochs.
Now I would like to set the random seed for the model so that the same images are always used for training and testing.[image]
Do I have to set the Random Seed at the beginning after my imports, when dividing it into training / test data, or when using the model.fit () function? How do I do it best and what does the code look like?

i would also like to know how i can measure the pearson correlation before and after training the model. (referring votes to numbers) and then compare them.

Tank you :)

Comment: I think when you already split the data,the data is no longer depended on the random_state,your train_dataset and test_dataset is now fixed

Comment: We generally do it at the beginning after imports, scikit learn provides [train_test_split] (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)which is very useful for splitting either with the random_state or not

Comment: (trainX, testX, trainY, testY)= train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=5) an example